# How do I manage pairing Visual Studio to multiple Mac's?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I work from home and for my job I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows paired to a MacinCloud running Big Sur using my company's Apple Developer account for Xamarin development.

In the evenings, I'm playing with MAUI so I'm running the Visual Studio 2022 "Preview" version and I have my own Apple Developer account and my own separate MacinCloud running Monterey.

When I open Visual Studio (either version) it looks like it just tries to pair to the last Mac I used and then it also tries to install updated SDK's etc. if necessary.

How do I manage this?  Ideally I want to stop it from auto-pairing and then choose the correct Mac each time.

Thanks in advance,

Paul Lonsdale.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Tools - Options - Xamarin - iOS Settings on Visual Studio on  Windows computer. On the Pair to Mac dialog window  select "Forget this connection" (right click context menu on the connection).

Comment: Hi, yeah I think this is my only option.  It just means I have to pair it up again each time I want to use it but that's no major issue.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but a workaround.  The issue only really happens when both macs are running which is rarely the case.  I will, in future, make sure that only the mac I need for the project I am working on is up and running.  That way even if VS tries to connect to the other one it will fail.

Comment: Please, as per the rules, use the comments if you don't have to post code.